# Remap Ctrl-D in vim

Tags: vim

I want to remap another key combo, say <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>, to function as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> does (note: not the same as <kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>).

What I have so far is:

```
nmap ^G :exe 'normal '.&scroll.'^E<CR>'
```

Bringing up my vim command mode and typing this in, it works perfectly. However, when I save my .vimrc and reload vim, I get the following error when pushing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>:

```
E114: Missing quote: '
E15: Invalid expression: 'normal '.&scroll.'
```

It seems to be stuck at not evaluating the ^E appropriately. However, I have been entirely unsuccessful in using  or any other way of specifying <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^G` and `^E` are special characters, and do not work well when you put them in the `.vimrc`. You need to use `<C-g>` and `<C-e>`, but since your Ctrl+E is placed inside a string, you need to escape it and write `\<C-e>`. You also need to use double quotes instead of single quotes - otherwise you can't do the escaping.

In other note - you should probably use `nnoremap` instead of `nmap`, so that if you remap `<C-e>` somewhere else, `<C-g>` will still behave like the original `<C-e>`.

Comment: I did not know about nnoremap! Because of this, I could do nnoremap <C-g> <C-d> and then remap <C-d> to something else. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just write `<C-E>` for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: :exec 'norm'.&scroll.'<C-E><cr>' does not work, either in a vim command (by hitting :) or when used in the mapping

Comment: As Idan pointed out, in a string you need to escape it like `\<C-E>`.